# Can PhpStorm show edited line status for code that's committed but not yet merged?

Tags: git, phpstorm

PHP shows a "line status" marker in the lefthand gutter indicating whether a line has been edited since "the last update" (per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-status-highlights.html#editor)

If you're using git, then any time you regularly commit your work like a good developer, you can no longer see which lines or files you have modified.

It would be nice if I could tell PhpStorm "please consider the `deploy-candidate` branch to be 'the last update', so I can easily see what I've actually changed in my current task's `BUG-9463-Fix-Login-Button` branch."

**So: Is there a setting to show all changes in your local branch as "edited"?**

Notes:

1) As an alternative, **a correct answer could be a git incantation** to fool the editor. I'd be OK with having to undo that incantation each time before I committed, and redo it after I push, since I can just automate that in .gitconfig anyway.

2) Ideally it'd also show which files were changed in your branch in the "local changes" tab, but while that'd be a bonus, it's not the focus of this question, nor required in a correct answer.

3) While it shows similar information, the undeniably awesome **diff tool is no substitute for line-status** indicators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this request submitted to the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24398

And it appears that someone has made a plugin partially addressing the request: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10083-git-scope

Comment: Accepted answer: the plugin you linked has resolved the issue, and while link-only answers are discouraged, I can think of no information on the links that would improve this answer (other than possibly that the issue is TEN YEARS OLD!). Through your links, I found another question about it, so I'm closing my question as a dup. Your answer would likely be valuable on that question, too, if you want to repost it there.